# GPIO: Warning Channel already in use

Tags: gpio, python, rpi.gpio

`gpio.py:5: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway. Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
  GPIO.setup(8, GPIO.OUT)`
That is what I get after I run:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(8, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(7, 0)
GPIO.output(8, 0)
```

Is there anyway I can fix the warning?

Comment: Also, what does GPIO.cleanup() do? Should I use it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This code helped me get rid of the warning (the "finally" part at the end):

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) # Broadcom pin-numbering scheme

GPIO.setup(6, GPIO.OUT) # output rf

# Initial state for LEDs:
print("Testing RF out, Press CTRL+C to exit")

try:
     print("set GIOP high")
     GPIO.output(6, GPIO.HIGH)
     time.sleep(5)               
except KeyboardInterrupt: # If CTRL+C is pressed, exit cleanly:
   print("Keyboard interrupt")

except:
   print("some error") 

finally:
   print("clean up") 
   GPIO.cleanup() # cleanup all GPIO
```

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Note that empty except clauses are dangerous [Use this with extreme caution, since it is easy to mask a real programming error in this way!](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)

Comment: Wow, you actually took the time to review my code and help. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can safely ignore the warning.

As the message says add GPIO.setwarnings(False) to the start of your script to disable warnings.

GPIO.cleanup() sets any GPIO you have used within RPi.GPIO to INPUT mode.  If that behaviour is desirable call the method before exiting your script.

Comment: Is there a way that I can repeat the script after every 5 minutes and after every loop turn the lights off.

Answer (score 0):

List item

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO 
from time import sleep

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) 
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT) 
GPIO.setup(8, GPIO.IN)     

state = "ON"

if GPIO.input(8) == 0: GPIO.output(7, GPIO.HIGH)
state = “OFF” 
print(state)
else:
GPIO.output(7, GPIO.LOW)
print(state)
```

Comment: Would you care to [edit] and explain your answer?